# I want to fetch ratings value from markeroptions.snippet and display the ratings on rating bar in infowindow

Tags: android

I am getting the rating value as float but I want to display that value in infowindow as ratingbar .

Comment: please show some of your code

Answer (score 0):

public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

```
                String snippet1 = marker.getTitle();
            String var = snippet1.substring(6, 9);



            try {
                if (!var.equals(null)) {
                    ratingBar1.setRating(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(var)));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "no ratings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.print("no ratings!!!");
            }

            LatLng ll = marker.getPosition();
            placename.setText(marker.getTitle());
            tvlat.setText("Longitute" + ll.latitude);
            tvlng.setText("Longitute" + ll.longitude);
            snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
            return v;

        }
    });
```